# b2contactlistener issues

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am making an iphone app with cocos2d and box2d and I am having trouble, I followed this tutorial on how to use the b2ContactListener because I need it very badly for my app... http://www.raywenderlich.com/505/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-22 I am trying to detect when two objects collide

It has been one of the hardest things for me to figure out... not nessecarally what he is doing in the game but how to use the b2contactlistener... However, I want to use what he did in that tutorial within my code

this is how I updated my tick method so it would check for collisions every time

```
-(void) update: (ccTime) dt
{
int32 velocityIterations = 8;
int32 positionIterations = 1;

// Instruct the world to perform a single step of simulation. It is
// generally best to keep the time step and iterations fixed.
world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);    


std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); 
    pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
    MyContact contact = *pos;

    if ((contact.fixtureA == _bottomFixture && contact.fixtureB == _ballFixture) ||
        (contact.fixtureA == _ballFixture && contact.fixtureB == _bottomFixture)) {
        NSLog(@"Ball hit bottom!");
    }
}
}
```

However, I don't know how to change it to work with my two b2Bodies, eggBody and locations.platform...

I believe it is these few lines I must change...

```
    if ((contact.fixtureA == _bottomFixture && contact.fixtureB == _ballFixture) ||
        (contact.fixtureA == _ballFixture && contact.fixtureB == _bottomFixture)) {
        NSLog(@"Ball hit bottom!");
    }
```

where it says _bottomFixture and _ballFixture I thought I would plug in my b2Bodies... but now I feel like _bottomFixture isn't even a b2body

:) any help would be great sorry if I confused anybody just post any questions and I will clarify thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_bottomFixture is a b2Fixture object.

It is created when you create the fixturedef of the body by

```
 bottomBody->CreateFixture(&_fixturedef);
```

the above line returns a b2Fixture.
so you can write

```
b2Fixture *_bottomFixture =  bottomBody->CreateFixture(&_fixturedef);
```

normally we don't track this b2Fixture object. But in collision detection, we need to use it.